# RxJS Observable Would be memory leak for this scene?

Tags: rxjs

javascript

```
for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
  const a = new Observable(observer => {});
  a.subscribe();
}
```

https://rxjs-playground.github.io/#/?js=for%28let%20i%20%3D%200%3B%20i%3C%201000000%3B%20%2B%2Bi%29%20%7B%0A%20%20let%20a%20%3D%20new%20Rx.Observable%28observer%20%3D%3E%20%7B%7D%29%3B%0A%20%20a.subscribe%28%29%3B%0A%7D

[image]

Comment: why do you suppose it should be memory leak? there are just scoped variables without any reference into/from global scope. for sure garbage collector will drop them shortly. or do you mean something behind?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be sure that there is no memory leak then do this:

```
a.pipe(finalize(()=>console.log(„no leak”))).subscribe()
```

This log should appear only when observable would complete. So you will be ensured that there is no memory leak. In my opinion this is the best way to check whether memory leak occurs.